# Client Side Partial For DevForce Entity cannot see Properties exposed in the models partial

Tags: c#, wpf, devforce

I am currently facing an issue where I am trying to make a WPF Client Side Partial of one of our Model First DevForce entities. The issue is that the partial in the WPF client does not seem to have access to the properties in it's sibling partial in the model project which the client project has referenced.

I have used the same namespace in both the client and the model but the client side keeps coming back as it is a partial with only a single file.

My main reasoning for this is that I need to access properties on a static class that resides in my client project within a property I am adding to the client side entity Partial. A sample of which follows:

Model Buddy Class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using IbEm = IdeaBlade.EntityModel;
using IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Security;
using IdeaBlade.Validation;

// ReSharper disable CheckNamespace
namespace BearPaw.Models.Main
{
[MetadataType(typeof(NavigationButtonGroupMetadata))]
public partial class NavigationButtonGroup
{

    [IbEm.AllowRpc]
    public static object NameAlreadyInUse(IPrincipal principal,
      IbEm.EntityManager entityManager, params Object[] args)
    {
        string buttonGroupNameToCheck = (string)args[0];

        var serverButtonGroup = entityManager.GetQuery<NavigationButtonGroup>().FirstOrDefault((u) => u.Name == buttonGroupNameToCheck);

        return serverButtonGroup != null;
    }

}

public class NavigationButtonGroupMetadata
{
    [RegexVerifier("Name", @"^[A-Za-z_]*$")]
    [StringLengthVerifier(MaxValue = 100, IsRequired = true, ErrorMessage = "Button Group Name must be unique")]
    public static string Name;
}

}
```

Client Side Partial:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using IbEm = IdeaBlade.EntityModel;
using IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Security;
using IdeaBlade.Validation;

// ReSharper disable CheckNamespace
namespace BearPaw.Models.Main
{
[MetadataType(typeof(NavigationButtonGroupMetadata))]
public partial class NavigationButtonGroup
{
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            {
                if (NavigationButtonGroupType.AlwaysVisible || (DynamicMenuItemsHelper.MenuDetails != null && DynamicMenuItemsHelper.MenuDetails.Count() > 0 )) return true;
                var currentUser = Authenticator.Instance?.DefaultAuthenticationContext?.Principal?.Identity;
                return currentUser != null && NavigationButtons.
                    Any(b => b.IsEnabled);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Visual Studio is showing compile errors on NavigationButtonGroupType.AlwaysVisible stating an object reference is required for the non-static field even though NavigationButtonGroupType is a nav prop on the entity in the model. A similar issue applies in that NavigationButtons is also a nav property but Visual Studio is stating that it doesn't exist in the current context.

Any help or pointers as to why this would not be working would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0):

A partial class definition allows you to spread a class definition over multiple files, but only in the same assembly.  This is a C# thing, not a DevForce restriction.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) for more information.

If I'm understanding correctly, you want some functionality of the entity class available only on the client (and some on the server too?).  If you're defining client and server model projects you can use conditional compilation to determine which features of the entity are available in each assembly.  This is fairly standard in DevForce SL applications, although maybe less used in WPF.

Another option is to put properties like this in the ViewModel, if you're using this type of architecture.

Comment: Hi Kim, thanks for that. I think I was misleading myself due to the following text from the IdeaBlade DRC "A cleaner and easier way is to create additional partial class files, either in the .NET project or in the client project, and deliberately not link them."

This made me think there was some "secret sauce" that could allow this.

This code was for some navigational structure that I was hoping to not have to write a whole VM for just to hold the structure and entities, looks like I may have to re-think that I guess. Thanks for the quick reply.